# get a dynamic image in jasperserver

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to call a dynamic image in jasperserver 8.0.0, the problem is that it is working for jasperstudio 6.19 but when I upload it to the server it shows me an error (The error message is to contact the administrator :D)

```
<image>
  <reportElement key="image-1" x="11" y="2" width="76" height="51" uuid="51d3ca8b-                                                    d083-4e86-9249-8fc9f7dbb1fa"/>
  <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{DIR} + $F{COD_EMPRESA}.toString()]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

[image]

COD_EMPRESA returns a number for example 10, and that 10 is the image.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by placing the images in a folder inside the server, since I worked locally and the folder was outside the server, in the image path I put the following code and it worked (the path points to the server and also works on jasperstudio)

```
"/images/"+ $F{COD_EMPRESA}.toString()
```